# Out of memory exception using J2ssh jar

Tags: ssh, weblogic, stack-overflow, j2ssh

We are using j2ssh jar(j2ssh is an external jar used to connect Secured Shell)in our webapp.The webapp is running in weblogic server.

I open the connection like this

```
SshClient ssh = new SshClient();
SessionChannelClient session=null;
session = ssh.openSessionChannel();
```

inside the finally block I close the session like this.

```
finally
{
  System.out.println("disconnecting from ssh");
  try
 {
   session.close();
 }
 catch(IOException ioe)
 {
  theOutput = ioe.getMessage();
  System.out.println("IOException="+ioe);
 }
}
```

My doubt is am I closing the connection properly? Will it clear the Weblogic stack because we are getting frequent complaints that users are getting exceptions due to memory overflow which basically means garbage collection is not happening properly.Once we restart the server it is automatically solved.Is there a way to periodically clear the weblogic memory so to avoid memory overflow exception?

Comment: is the out of memory related only to this code? there can be other optimizations as well w.r.t. closing connections, resultsets and so on. Is there a stacktrace or evidence this is the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try releasing the **session** and **ssh** object after closing session,

something like this after catch block,

```
finally {
 session = null;   
 ssh = null;
}
```